# Higher Order Torsion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curvature

Define an k-Torsion as a measure of how much a parametrically defined curve $x(t)$ where $t$ is a real scalar and $x$ is a vector in $R^n$ deviates from the locally encapsulating k-dimensional hyperplane at t.

How do you measure k-torsion in n dimensional parametric curves? It's trivial to measure it $R^3$ but the use of the cross product doesn't generalize easily (wedge products require a lot of vectors).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas#Formulas_in_n_dimensions